# Adding Parent Columns to an Excel PivotTable using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I'm trying to use Apache-POI to create a PivotTable in Excel with data that was retrieved from a database.
Currently I can create normal column labels on the pivot table, but I want to be able to add a parent column table.

This is how I want my table to look:
[image]

This is how I am creating the pivot table:

```
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference(
    fromSheet.getSheetName() + "!" + tableRange),
    new CellReference("A6"));

pivotTable.addRowLabel(0); // the row label

pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2, "Child Column 1");
pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3, "Child Column 2");
```

How can I add a parent column that contains both child columns?

Answer (score 2):

You should add parent column in "Column Labels" instead of "Value".

But POI API didn't provide addColumn function, try below function to add parent column to Column Label

```
public static void addColumLabels(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable, int columnIndex) {
    AreaReference pivotArea = getPivotArea(pivotTable);
    int lastColIndex = pivotArea.getLastCell().getCol() - pivotArea.getFirstCell().getCol();

    if (columnIndex > lastColIndex && columnIndex < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    CTPivotFields pivotFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields();

    CTPivotField pivotField = CTPivotField.Factory.newInstance();
    CTItems items = pivotField.addNewItems();

    pivotField.setAxis(STAxis.AXIS_COL);
    pivotField.setShowAll(false);
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastColIndex; i++) {
        items.addNewItem().setT(STItemType.DEFAULT);
    }
    items.setCount(items.sizeOfItemArray());
    pivotFields.setPivotFieldArray(columnIndex, pivotField);

    // colfield should be added for the second one.
    CTColFields colFields;
    if (pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields() != null) {
        colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getColFields();
    } else {
        colFields = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields();
    }
    colFields.addNewField().setX(columnIndex);
    colFields.setCount(colFields.sizeOfFieldArray());
}
```